# how to regex match string escaped with sql style?

Tags: sql, regex

examples:

```
"""Romeo and Juliet"""
'another string that is quoted with '' single quotes'
```

the problem is that the string can have characters used for db escaping even in it's beginning and end, so regex should look if given char is used in sequence of odd length that is 1,3,5... at the end of matched string

Comment: For what database?  SQL Server doesn't support regex without CLR (2005+), Oracle support starts at 10g...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this regex: `'(?:[^']|'')*'` for single quotes. The same for double quotes, i.e. full regex:

```
'(?:[^']|'')*'|"(?:[^"]|"")*"
```

In string `hello 'my ''beautiful''' 'world'! """Romeo and Juliet"""` it will find:

1. `'my ''beautiful'''`
2. `'world'`
3. `"""Romeo and Juliet"""`

Answer (score -1):

Where your string includes (or might include) characters that cause problems in your sql, you should *always* escape.

If you're using PHP with a mysql database, use `mysql_real_escape_string($text);` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php))

For other databases and languages, you'll have to check for your specific purposes, but there's likely to be an existing method.

Comment: I don't want to escape these strings, I have already escaped them. I want to fish out these escaped string from sql command using regex.