# Flex/Yacc: What is the regex for SQL string literal?

Tags: yacc, flex-lexer

I have the following rule:

```
string_literal \'(\\.|[^\\'])*\'
```

But this is assumes ' are escaped with a backslash but in SQL you can use '' to mean a single quote as well. What is the correct regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adapted this solution:

```
string_literal '([^\']|''|\')*'
```

From this other post https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718928/1470961

Answer (score 0):

Escaped character can be not only <single quote> but any character. 
So here are 2 alternatives:

```
('(\\.|[^'])*')+
```

or

```
'(\\.|''|[^'])*'
```